# Questions on proof of Gödel's Completeness Theorem in A Friendly Introduction to Mahematical Logic by Leary and Kristiansen

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In [Proposition 3.2.6](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/03%3A_Completeness_and_Compactness/3.02%3A_Completeness), the authors are trying to prove that the structure $\mathfrak{U}$, whose universe is the equivalence classes of the variable free terms, models the set of sentences $\Sigma'$ using induction.

They use the usual trick of completing the proof by doing induction on complexity of the formula like they do [here in Theorem 1.4.2](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/01%3A_Structures_and_Languages/1.05%3A_Induction). But when it comes to proving the base cases which is showing that statement $\sigma \in \Sigma^\prime \: \text{if and only if} \: \mathfrak{A} \models \sigma$ holds for the relations, they only consider the variable free terms, not all of the terms. How do I justify this? Shouldn't we prove for all terms instead of just the variable free terms?

Also, when proving $\sigma \in \Sigma^\prime \: \text{if and only if} \: \mathfrak{A} \models \sigma$ for statements of the form $\forall x \varphi$, the authors say that $\varphi^x_{t}$ is less complex than $\forall x \varphi$ so the induction hypothesis holds for $\varphi^x_{t}$. How do I make all of these rigorous?

I'm looking for a proper justification of all these arguments. What should I be doing induction on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to avoid free variables comes from the fact that all the elements of the structure we're looking at are named by closed terms: to check that $\mathfrak{A}\models\forall x\varphi(x)$ we just need to check that $\mathfrak{A}\models\varphi(t)$ for each closed term $t$. This is **not true for all structures in general** - it's a very special feature of the structure $\mathfrak{A}$ built in the proof.

(On the other hand, every structure $\mathfrak{B}$ has an *expansion* $\hat{\mathfrak{B}}$ gotten by adding new constant symbols naming all the elements. We then can just work with sentences in the $\hat{\mathfrak{B}}$-context rather than with formulas in the $\mathfrak{B}$-context. This language-expansion trick is really just a repackaging of variable assignments, but it can frequently be convenient; I personally prefer it.)

As to the measure of complexity, this is the same as (in my experience anyways) all the usual arguments by induction on complexity: we count logical operators, that is, Booleans and quantifiers. From "$\forall x\varphi(x)$" to "$\varphi(t)$" is clearly a step down, regardless of how complicated the term $t$ is, **since terms cannot use logical operators**.

Comment: By closed term, do you mean variable free term?

Comment: @ashK Yes, that's right.